# Overriding ordering of related object in queryset

Tags: django

I have two related models, `Customer` and `Config`. Customer is set to automatically order by `order`. Now I want to select the **latest** `Config` entry for each distinct set of `customer` and `report_type`.

That's usually accomplished by an `order_by` on all the distinct fields as well as a descending ordering on the date, followed by a `distinct` on the distinct fields.

However, since Django sneaks in another `ORDER BY` on `Customer.order` in the eventual query, `DISTINCT` says its arguments don't match those of `ORDER BY`. I'd like to override the ordering on `Customer` in this case.

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["order"]


class Config:
    customer = models.ForeignKeyField(Customer)
    created = models.DatetimeField()
    report_type = models.TextField()

cfgs = (
    Report.objects
    .filter()
    .order_by("customer", "report_type", "-created")
    .distinct("customer", "report_type")
)
```

There is a solution, albeit one I feel is a little bit hacky. By doing the `order_by` and `distinct` calls on the `customer_id` field, it won't try to `LEFT JOIN` `Customer` and also forego its ordering.

The problem here is that that means I'll have to make another database call to fetch the `Customer` objects. It's not a big deal, but if I could override the ordering on `Customer`, that would be a great deal better.

```py
cfgs = (
    Report.objects
    .filter()
    .order_by("customer_id", "report_type", "-created")  # using customer_id instead of customer works
    .distinct("customer_id", "report_type")
)
```